# Count rows where date is inside current month with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that checks the date column of a row and checks it is within the current month, then checks a separate column in a row and checks it is equal to some text, the formula would then output a count of instances where that is true.

For reference, the columns are named as two ranges, **LeadDate** and **LeadAcquisitionChannel**.

[edit] The Refers to: definitions are:

```
'LeadDate Refers to:
=OFFSET('Enquiry Log'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Enquiry Log'!$A:$A),1) 'LeadAcquisitionChannel Refers to:
=OFFSET('Enquiry Log'!$J$2,0,0,COUNTA('Enquiry Log'!$J:$J),1)
```

I ran the date check with following **formula**:

```
=COUNTIF(LeadDate,">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)
```

Which was successful in telling me how many entries fall within the current month.

So I assumed I could then add the multiple criteria in a COUNTIFS **like this:**

```
=COUNTIFS(LeadDate,">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),LeadAcquisitionChannel,B27)
```

B27 being a cell containing the text I want to check for.

This formula returns me a #VALUE! **error**.

Any ideas as to why this is happening or whether there is an alternative method I can use?

Comment: Are LeadDate and LeadAcquisitionChannel the same number of cells and either a single column or single row?

Comment: They are I believe, each range increases by one when a new entry row has been input. @Jeeped

Comment: Then they should share the same terminator. Whatever is used to determine the last row for LeadDate should be used for LeadAcquisitionChannel exactly while INDEX references a different column. Share the Refers to: for each.

Comment: LeadDate Refers to: 
=OFFSET('Enquiry Log'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Enquiry Log'!$A:$A),1)

LeadAcquisitionChannel Refers to: 
=OFFSET('Enquiry Log'!$J$2,0,0,COUNTA('Enquiry Log'!$J:$J),1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here lies in the Refers to: definitions for both LeadDate and LeadAcquisitionChannel as COUNTIFS requires that each criteria range be the same size and shape of cells.

For a dynamic list of dates that grows when new dates are added:

```
='Enquiry Log'!$a$2:index('Enquiry Log'!$a:$a, match(1e99, 'Enquiry Log'!$a:$a))
```

For a matching dynamic list of other information in an adjacent column use the same terminating row like this:

```
='Enquiry Log'!$j$2:index('Enquiry Log'!$j:$j, match(1e99, 'Enquiry Log'!$a:$a))
```

Each of these refers to a column of data extending down in each individual column to the row containing the last date in column A.

Your original relied on individual COUNTA counts to reshape OFFSET. There is no guarantee that there isn't an interim blank row or that they each continue down to the same row. You could homogenize the originals with,

```
=OFFSET('Enquiry Log'!$J$2, 0, 0, COUNTA('Enquiry Log'!$A:$A), 1)
```

... but that still doesn't guarantee that interim blank cells in column A wouldn't skew results.

Comment: Ahhh it all makes sense.

Great solution and very well explained. 

Thanks very much @jeeped.

Comment: fwiw, if you were trying to locate the last text value in a column you would use `match("zzz", 'Enquiry Log'!$a:$a)` but both numbers and dates are found with 1e99. In your case we are locating the last date in column A so it doesn't matter whether column J is text, numbers or dates,

Comment: You've just solved another issue I ran into when looking for the last text value somewhere else in my workbook! Thank you.